# How does form_for decide what action is to be taken for a particular request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I wrote the following **code**:-

```
<%= form_for(:session,url: login_path) do |f| %>
```

which got translated to

```
<form action="/login" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

my **routes.rb** file contains the following code:-

```
root 'static_pages#home' 
get 'contact'=>'static_pages#contact' 
get 'about'=>'static_pages#about'
get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
get 'signup' => 'users#new'
get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
post 'login' => 'session#create'
delete 'logout' => 'session#destroy'
resources:users
```

I want to know how the action of `form_for` is being decided?

Comment: What is `@user` here? Also update your question with `routes.rb` code

Comment: I have updated my code a bit and also provided the routes.rb code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out the Rails Form Helper Guide in particular the section on [dealing with model objects.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects)  Also, the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) for form_for.

To your question, in

```
  <form action="/login" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"> 
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           this bit
```

is coming from a combination of the object you're passing to the `form_for` helper

```
  <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>
               ^^^^^^^^
                 here
```

Along with the url you are (optionally) passing into the `form_for` helper

```
  <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                              here
```

As Joe Half Face alludes to in his answer, `:session` is a `symbol`, and so `form_for` resolves `login_path` simply to `action="/login"`.

If `:session`, instead, had been an instance variable (let's imagine you have a `Session` class and an instance variable like `@session`), then your `form_for` call may have looked something like this:

```
  <%= form_for(@session, url: login_path) do |f| %>
```

then `form_for` would have resolved the `action=` differently, depending on the state of the `@session` object (is it a new record? an already-saved record? etc.).

BTW, `form_for` does **not require** the `url` argument. So, it's okay to do:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
```

In this case, `form_for` use the provided `@user` object to infer the correct path and you get

```
<form action="/users" ... >
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, where you don't specify instance object (`@model_name`), it just assigns form path to path you provide: `login_path`, method which just outputs "/login".

There are two routes

```
get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
post 'login' => 'session#create'
```

But as form_for default HTTP verb would be post, Rails matches incoming post request with `'login' => 'session#create'`.

Method `login_path` is auto defined as you provide string `'login'`, unless you specify something other like post `'login' => 'session#create', as: "sign_in"`, which would do `sing_in_path`.

It is part of Rails backwards meta programming.

Comment: Thank u **Joe Half Face** but there is still a doubt, what if the routes.rb file is same and the code is as follow:- <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %> ** what i see is the that this code gets translated to **action="/users" just curious to know how in this case without providing the path is the form_for figuring out the action to be performed. Here @user is the database model object basically this form for is being used to create a signup page.

Answer (score 0):

if `@user` not persisted it push you to `update` action

if not persisted - to `create`

but you can configure `form_for` by yourself

```
form_for @user, url: {action: "create"}
```